# How and where can I place my Bubble sort algorithm in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, bufferedreader, bubble-sort

I am trying to create a program that will ask the user to input 20 double values. The program will then add the total of all input and compute the average. Then I need to display the sum, average, values less than 5.00 and values greater that the computed average. So far, I am able to do that. However, we were also asked to display all elements in descending order. We were introduced to bubble sorting but I cannot figure out where and how to place it in my current codes because it's affecting the other results. We are only allowed to use BufferedReader for this by the way.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Prices {
public static void main(String[]args)throws IOException{

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    double [] price = new double [5];
    double sum = 0, ave = 0, temp;

    System.out.print("Enter a value that has a decimal point: " );

    for(int i=0; i<price.length;i++) 
 //loop for accepting values for the array, adding values and getting the ave of the values
    {

        price[i] = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());//holds the values of the input

        sum += price[i];//adds all the input
        ave = sum/5;//divides the computed sum by array size
    }
    // for printing the total sum & ave
    System.out.println("The sum is = "+sum);
    System.out.println("The average is = "+ave);

    for(int i=0; i<price.length;i++){//loop for displaying values<5.00 and values>computed ave.    
    if (price[i]<5.00)
    {   
        System.out.println("Values less than 5.00: "+ price[i]);
    }
    if (price[i]>ave)
    {
        System.out.println("Values greater than average: "+ price[i]);
    }
    }  
}
}
```

Comment: sort it after you have entered in all valid values for the array. Ex. Right above the system.out.println(sum is = ...) line of code

Answer (score 1):

You might want to place your BubbleSort algorythm at the end, in the 'main' method after the closure of the last if statement so that whatever change it makes to the array it is not going to interfere with the rest of the program.

Alternatively you could create a copy of the array to work on so that the main array is not affected no matter where you place the algorythm in the method, but I don't recomend doing that in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any sort happening here. All that is happening is looping thru the array and printing to std out.

Create a new method call bubbleSort in the Prices class and pass in the array that was read to this method. A simple implementation is here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Implementation Bubble sort is an in-place sort, so the original array will get modified.